# Having Trouble With VB.NET Registry Editing

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm trying to make a simple program that will add a value to a specific part of my Windows Registry when I press a button, but it keeps adding it in the wrong place. I specified the right location of where I want the thing to be added. So, I don't know why it's doing that, but I'd like to find out how I can fix it so it will add it in the right place. This is my code so far:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
    Dim subkey As RegistryKey
    subkey = key.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ashampoo\Ashampoo MouseTracer\legend", True)
    My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.SetValue("day6Value", 99999999999.999)
End Sub
```

It places the thing that I want to add in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER root directory, instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ashampoo\Ashampoo MouseTracer\legend

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remove HKEY_CURRENT_USER from the string.  And use Registry.CurrentUser instead of Registry.LocalMachine

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I'll try that out and see if it works. I'll report back soon.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the problem looks to be here:

```
subkey = key.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ashampoo\Ashampoo MouseTracer\legend", True)
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.SetValue("day6Value", 99999999999.999)
```

You set the subkey but then, instead of adding to it, you add to the CurrentUser.

Try this:

```
subkey = key _
    .OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ashampoo\Ashampoo MouseTracer\legend", True)
subkey.CreateSubKey("day6Value")
subkey.SetValue("day6Value", 99999999999.999)
```

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ashampoo\Ashampoo MouseTracer\legend", true);
key.SetValue("key", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
key.close();
```

VB

```
Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ashampoo\Ashampoo           MouseTracer\legend", True)
key.SetValue("key", "1", RegistryValueKind.[String])
key.close()
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help, but I keep getting an exception that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". I tried modifying the code as much as I could to try to get it to work, but now it's just getting to the point that I'm starting to get really pissed off. I looked up on Google for an answer to this problem and one of the links took me to the Microsoft site where another person is having the same problem as me. One of the guys said "When you call OpenSubKey, it will return null if the key doesn't exist." How the hell is that even possible?! The key does exist!

Comment: def, works just fired it up in a console real quick. different path was the only change and just added a new dword key to test. throw some breaks in and see if you can't sort out at what point its failing.